# What is this fund?

Tags: index-fund, portfolio, fidelity

I have a 401k account with Fidelity consisting of various funds. For whatever reason Fidelity will display *today's* +/- % for each ticker symbol, but it does not display *overall* growth since purchase. I assume their reasoning is something to do with the funds not having a real "cost basis" because they were purchased with pre-tax dollars, though that's just guessing.

I found that by importing all of the transactions into a Google Finance portfolio, I am able to see the overall performance for each fund, including closed positions. The ending balances exactly match what Fidelity is currently showing (I imported all +ve transactions as "Buy" and all -ve transactions as "Sell", so that reinvested dividends show up as the right amount of shares for each fund), so I'm pretty happy so far.

This has worked according to my expectations for all except one fund - "**TD7A**", which Fidelity describes simply as "SMID CAP FUND". I have no idea what this is. I can't find seem to find the symbol on any other finance sites, and the description matches a whole bunch of funds, but I haven't found any that match the historic prices of this fund in my account. Fidelity does offer charts for the fund's performance since inception (7/1/2016), breakdown of holdings, etc., but Google doesn't recognize the symbol, so I don't know how to import it.

There is a note on the research page that reads: *Information on this investment option was provided by your plan sponsor, plan trustee, investment manager, trustee or third party data provider. This investment is not a mutual fund.*

Does anyone else have this fund and/or know how to track it outside of Fidelity?

Comment: Taxes have nothing to do with cost basis, you should ask Fidelity about TD7A

Answer (score 4):

SMID CAP FUND is Fidelity's way of saying SMALL to MID CAP FUND.  Small to Medium is self explanatory.  Cap is capitalization, and it basically means how much the sum of all the existing shares of the company are worth.  Fidelity names the funds inside their 401k plans according to who provides the fund.  They also provide management resources for funds chosen by your employer.

There should be more available about the fund you're interested in on your Fidelity 401(k) site.